# Using a global vector of structs

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector, struct

I am trying to globally declare – and initialize – a vector of structs. My code is the following:

```
Struct creation (in header file vsystem.h)
    struct var {
        string name;
        float value;
    };

Variable (in source file vsystem.cpp)
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    vector <var> varList;
```

Both of those `# include <string>` and `<vector>`. I have also tried

```
vector <var> varList ();
```

But that doesn't work either. My error is

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token
```

On a side note, my `setVar` function is triggering an error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - 'string' was not declared in this scope
    - expected primary-expression before 'float'
    - initializer expression list treated as compound 
     expression
    - expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
```

Code:

```
int setVar(string varName, float value){
    // Check to see if varName already exists
    varExists = false;
    for (int i=0; i<varList.size(); i++){
        if (varList[i].name == varName){
            varExists = true;
            return ERR_VAR_EXISTS;
        }
    }

    // Good! The variable doesn't exist yet.
    var tempVar ();
    var.name = varName;
    var.value = value;
    varList.push_back(tempVar);
    return 0;
}
```

Help please!

I am running Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 with G++ compiler on Mac 10.6.7.

Comment: Please, use the preview feature and format the code.

Comment: Note that if you are trying to store name/value pairs that you intend to look up by name, a `std::map<std::string, float>` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector` is in the `std` namespace.  You need to qualify it as `std::vector` in your declaration:

```
std::vector <var> varList;
```

(Alternatively you could use a using declaration, `using std::vector;`, if you really hate the `std::`.)

Similarly for `string`; it needs to be qualified as `std::string`.  All of the names in the C++ Standard Library are in the `std` namespace except (a) those that are macros and (b) those that are in the legacy C headers (the ones that end in **.h**)

Comment: And yet he should have three includes:
`#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "vsystem.h"` - not two.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I've just added a using namespace std. I'll look into std::map. Also, how do you preview a post?  

@c-smile: that fixed some other stuff, thanks; didn't know you had to include it, but it makes sense.

I'll made a new thread for my other gazillion errors…